# Showing inequality of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion, supremum-and-infimum

Can anybody help me to show the first inequality in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUdUX.png) proof?
It is about standard Brownian Motion. So B(t) is a Brownian Motion and I know the rescaling and shifting properties of Brownian Motions but I don't know how to handle the supremum and how to get the $2^n m^2$ out of the $\mathbb{P}$?

The second inequality is clear.

Would be great if somebody could give me a hint!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an application of the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole's_inequality):
$$P\left(\sup \limits_{i = 1}^n X_i > c\right) = P\left(\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^n \{X_i > c\}\right) \le \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n P(X_i > c) \le n \sup \limits_{i = 1}^n P(X_i > c)$$

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!